# Get current product in observer Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer

With my code, my product is not added (the "add to cart button" is not clickable after I clicked on in on the first time, I have to refresh)

I believe that's because my code isn't right, so I need help (to get the current product in my observer)

This is my code:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;    
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class RestrictAddToCart implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $registry;
    private $product;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    /**
     * add to cart event handler.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     *
     * @return RestrictAddToCart
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $id = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->geId();

        $test = false;
        if ($test == false) {
            $this->_messageManager->addErrorMessage(__($id));
            //set false if you not want to add product to cart
            $observer->getRequest()->setParam('product', false);
            return $this;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Using event**

> controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add

Comment: On which event, you are trying to observe?

Comment: controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add, as suggested here : https://webkul.com/blog/restrict-add-cart-according-condition-magneto2/

Answer (score 0):

**you could try to set the product param to false and then set the return_url param:**

```
  $observer->getRequest()->setParam('product', false);
  $observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url', $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
  $this->_messageManager->addError(__('This product cannot be added to your cart.'));
```

Comment: I need to get the current product, I don't get the purpose of your code

Comment: you can use controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add   event  here you can get product id .  $addedItemId = $observer->getRequest()->getParam('product');

Answer (score 0):

As you are injecting registry object, you can use the following code to get the current product object

```
$this->registry->registry('current_product');
```